# How to append array element with increasing the array count with key in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I've array `$a`

```
$a[1] = "A";
$a[2] = "B";
$a[3] = "C";
$a[4] = "D";
```

Let's say, `"X"` is new value that I want append middle position in `array`, I want to add it to 2nd `array` position that is `$a[2]` but I want to increase the count `keys` of `array` that will become like:

```
$a[1] = "A";
$a[2] = "X";
$a[3] = "B";
$a[4] = "C";
$a[5] = "D";
```

In this case, I want to implement this within a loop by checking some conditions with if, I tried with slice and splice both are not working

Comment: [`array_splice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) does what you need but it reindexes the values starting from `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like below:-

```
<?php

$a = array( 1=>'A', 2=>'B', 3=>'C', 4=>'D' );

$b = array( 'x' ); 

array_splice( $a, 1, 0, $b  );

$a = array_combine(range(1, count($a)), array_values($a));

print_r($a);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/837366

Answer (score 3):

I think , you can try this

```
$a = array( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' );
$b = array( 'x' ); 

array_splice( $a, 3, 0, $b  ); // splice in at position 3
```

Comment: No he don't want this:- https://eval.in/837358  .compare your output with OP's desired output

Comment: @Alive to Die , i was just giving teh example for his problem

Answer (score 2):

Use php funtion to do this array_splice

```
<?php 
    $a = array( 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' );
    $b = array( 'X' ); //  array optional or 
    //$b= 'x';
    array_splice( $a, 1, 0, $b  ); // splice in at position 1
    print_r($a);
    ?>
```

Comment: OP don't want  what you said. check this output of your code:-https://eval.in/837699 and compare it with the desired output of OP. Both are different